# Отмена эффекта от :hover

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Есть меню, в некоторых пунктах подменю. При открытии сайта на компьютерах и в разрешениях до 768px применяться эффект через псевдо класс :hover. Так вот проблема в том, что мне нужно как то отменить эффект наведения ниже разрешения 768px, (видимо как то в медиа запросе это возможно сделать) а затем, на разрешениях ниже 768px применять скрипт jQuery, который есть ниже по переключению класса.

В приоритете - как активизировать мой скрипт jQuery только на разрешениях ниже 768px. Как это возможно реализовать?

Вот меню:

```js
  $('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.topmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6EA3DD;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.topmenu>li>a.actual-menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FBC7CB;
}

.down:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #6EA3DD;
  left: 47%;
  bottom: -7px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #E6855F;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FBC7CB;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #95BCE6;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: -35%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
  z-index: 150;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(0%, 15px);
}

.topmenu>li:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="navigate" class="navigate">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="navigate__menu">
          <nav>
            <ul class="topmenu">
              <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" hreflang="en" class="down">Learn French</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Why study French?</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">French on Skype</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A few steps</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Our French lessons</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ourtutor.html" hreflang="en">Our Tutor</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Нужно именно отменить те эффекты которые есть у элемента с :hover, а не добавлять что то другое

Comment: Да, Максим, нужно чтобы на ссылку 'a' уже не действовал псевдоэлемент :hover при разрешении ниже 768px. Так как будто его нет вообще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы отменить действие `hover` достаточно сделать по умолчанию то что вы делаете при событие `hover` .

Здесь Вы это увидите если посмотрите пример сначала **свёрнутый** а потом развёрнутый **на всю страницу**

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
  display:inline-block;
}
ul a,
ul span {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: blue;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  li ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><span>item2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

по поводу второго вопроса , как включать script при при определённом разрешении экрана. Делается это так:

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {

      if ($(document).width() < 768) {
        $.getScript("script.js");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если слегка отойти в сторону от вашего вопроса, то само по себе создание выпадающих меню при наведении — это антипаттерн в интерфейсах, просто по той причине, что человек без мышки или человек, который не может адекватно воспользоваться мышкой, не сможет раскрыть это меню. Как минимум, стоит добавить открытие меню по фокусу на элемент.

Далее, я бы на вашем месте не привязывался к определенному разрешению при загрузке и подключению скрипта-обработчика, потому что во-первых, айпэды сейчас пусть и начинаются с 768 пикселей по ширине в портретном режиме, но есть также и ландшафтный, а есть и еще много всего, кроме айпэдов. А во-вторых, есть, к примеру, ноутбуки с сенсорным экраном, а какие устройства будут через год — никому точно неизвестно.

В общем, я бы сделал как-то так:

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function firstTouch () {
  document.body.classList.add('touch-device')
  
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', firstTouch, false)
}, false)

document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
  var dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('.down')
    
  if (e.target.matches('.down')) {
    dropdownBtn.classList.toggle('down--active')
  } else {
    dropdownBtn.classList.remove('down--active')
  }
})
```

```css
.topmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6EA3DD;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.topmenu>li>a.actual-menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FBC7CB;
}

.down:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #6EA3DD;
  left: 47%;
  bottom: -7px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #E6855F;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FBC7CB;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #95BCE6;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: -35%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
  z-index: 150;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(0%, 15px);
}

:not(.touch-device) .down:hover + .submenu,
:not(.touch-device) .down:focus + .submenu,
.down.down--active + .submenu,
.submenu:focus-within {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="navigate" class="navigate">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="navigate__menu">
          <nav>
            <ul class="topmenu">
              <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" hreflang="en" class="down">Learn French</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Why study French?</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">French on Skype</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A few steps</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Our French lessons</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ourtutor.html" hreflang="en">Our Tutor</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

- Определять использовался ли тач;
- построить логику ховера и фокуса, основываясь на классе `.touch-device`;
- добавить в логику `:focus-within`;
- не подгружать скрипт в зависимости от разрешения.